# haproxy zero downtime in docker

Tags: docker, haproxy

I use haproxy and achieve zero downtime using "expose-fd listeners" feature. When I use haproxy docker, container gives error because of line "stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners" in haproxy config file. How can I achieve haproxy zero downtime in docker?

Comment: *"container gives error"* ...what's the error message?

Comment: Error: Starting frontend GLOBAL: cannot bind UNIX socket [/run/haproxy/admin.sock]